# How to check whether Vim is built as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Tags: vimscript, microsoft-windows, version

How do I check if Vim is compiled as 64-bit or 32-bit from within vimscript? Specifically on Windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Testing the value of the `win64` feature should tell you:

```
:echo has("win64")
```

If the output is `1`, then your Vim installation is 64-bit.

See:

```
:help has()
:help feature-list
```

and search for `64`.

Comment: To anyone that wonders how to use `has`, in command mode, you should type `:echo has("win64")`