# How can I check if Vim is 32 bit or 64 bit? (On Linux!)

Tags: linux, version

How can I find out if the vim I'm using is 32 or 64 bit? I'm using Ubuntu so [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-check-whether-vim-is-built-as-a-32-bit-or-64-bit-application) doesn't apply to me, I think. Also I checked

```
:version
```

and got this output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:21:49)
Inklusive der Korrekturen: 1-429
Verändert von pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Übersetzt von buildd@
Riesige Version mit GTK2 GUI. Ein- (+) oder ausschließlich (-) der Eigenschaften:
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info
 +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra
+extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap
+langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +path_extra +perl
+persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff
+startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
+toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11
-xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
          System-vimrc-Datei: "$VIM/vimrc"
        Benutzer-vimrc-Datei: "$HOME/.vimrc"
         Benutzer-exrc-Datei: "$HOME/.exrc"
         System-gvimrc-Datei: "$VIM/gvimrc"
       Benutzer-gvimrc-Datei: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
           System-Menü-Datei: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
     Voreinstellung für $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Übersetzt: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/
include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -fstack-protecto
r --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include/tcl8.5  -
D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1
Linken: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-nee
ded -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfo
ntconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/
lib -llua5.1  -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config
 -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5 -ldl -lpthread -lieee -lm -
lruby1.8 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

but it doesn't look like it tells me what I want to know.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is that information important for you?

Comment: Because I'm trying to open a large file (5.1GB)

Comment: @caligula might be useful: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/149/how-can-i-open-very-large-files-with-good-performance

Comment: Yes thanks, I'm actually already using that (including the linked stuff), but I'm still having problems. Perhaps I'll soon be able to ask a question, but for now I'm still trying...

Comment: ANd you are trying to open a 5.1 GB file for *editing* or for *viewing*? If the latter, why not use a pager instead? Or some grep/sed before sending to Vim?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the former ;) Question is incoming :/

Comment: `-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/...` - those are 64-bit includes.

Comment: In this case since you're on a 64-bit system and the gcc options don't include `-m32`, it's 64-bit. It's safe to assume that any package that came with your system is 64-bit, except for a very few rare apps that are only available in 32-bit form. The situation isn't the same as Windows where very many apps are still 32-bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're on Ubuntu, use the [`file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/file.1) command:

```
$ file -L "$(command -v vim)"
/usr/bin/vim.gnome: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=acb723f1249782755116f93ed45a30e7115ff423, stripped
```

As you can see, my `vim` is 64-bit.

We need to use  `-L` since `/usr/bin/vim` on Ubuntu is a symlink, managed by the [Debian alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives), and GNU `file` by default doesn't follow symlinks (thanks to Random832 for pointing this out!).

Or you can check the package architecture:

```
$ dpkg-query -f '${Package;10}\t${Architecture}\n' -W vim vim-gnome
       vim  amd64
 vim-gnome  amd64
```

---

Both of the above commands check the default `vim` as Carpetsmoker notes. Within Vim, you can do something like:

```
if system('file -L "' . exepath(v:progpath) . '"') =~ "64-bit"
    echo "yes"
endif
```

Or we can use Carpetsmoker's suggestion of the `/proc/$PID/exe` special link, which should be the most portable across Linux systems:

```
if system('file -L /proc/' . getpid() . '/exe' ) =~ "64-bit"
    echo "yes"
endif
```

---

`/proc/$PID/exe` is special. You can obtain the original executable for that process from `/proc/$PID/exe` even if it has been deleted, moved or replaced. In such cases, the output of [`readlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/readlink.1) or `resolve()` on it may not be what you expect. For example, using a temporary copy of `bash` for illustration:

```
$ readlink  -f /proc/$$/exe
/tmp/bash (deleted)
$ file "$(readlink -f /proc/$$/exe)"
/tmp/bash (deleted): ERROR: cannot open `/tmp/bash (deleted)' (No such file or directory)
```

However, instructing `file` to follow the symlink, or using `file - < /proc/self/exe` to read directly from it, which works fine:

```
$ file -L /proc/$$/exe
/proc/10958/exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b73723270773c893cf697d20c8d698f86a51635d, stripped
$ file - < /proc/self/exe
/dev/stdin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b73723270773c893cf697d20c8d698f86a51635d, stripped
```

We can't use the `/proc/self/exe` shortcut in Vim's call to `system()`, or as an argument to `file`, since then `self` will refer to the shell used to execute the command (if we used `file - </proc/self/exe`), or to `file` itself (if we used `file -L /proc/self/exe`). We *could* use `/proc/self/exe` if we were to read the file from Vim directly - which is what [Carpetsmoker's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3763/205) does.

Comment: How about the `$MACHTYPE` environment variable? I'm not sure how portable that is, though, but at least `tcsh` and `bash` seem to set it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker hmmm... What if you have 32-bit vim on a 64-bit system? (Say, `sudo apt-get install vim:i386` on a 64-bit Ubuntu)

Comment: Yeah, it would only check what the host system's using, not how Vim is compiled... Also a small caveat about your answer: it doesn't necessarily check the Vim binary you're running, but rather the 'default' Vim (which may be a different binary).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker how about the update?

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but you can use this to get the path to the current binary: `resolve('/proc/' . getpid() . '/exe')` ... Should work on most Unix-y systems which have a `/proc`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes, the `/proc/$PID/exe` should be safer in case the running binary got deleted or replaced.

Comment: Wow, that's more complicated than expected. The first two approaches work, but I don't understand how I could use the "within-vim-way": I tried putting this into the vimrc or executing it directly...

Comment: If it helps: Vim ist telling me: `E121: Undefined variable: v:progpath`

Comment: @caligula if you put that in vimrc as-si, you would get `yes`  then `Press Enter or type command to continue` when you start a 64-bit vim. (At least, I do.) It all depends on why you want to know this. As I understand it, the APIs on Windows change depending on whether you have win64 or win32 or something else, that's why they have that check. APIs on Linux usually don't change because you have 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @caligula if that's the case `v:progpath` must have been introduced in Vim 7.4. Try Carpetsmoker's test: `if system('file "' . resolve('/proc/' . getpid() . '/exe') . '"') =~ "64-bit" ...`

Comment: Ok, had some trouble I can't reproduce, but it's working now anyways :) Thx

Comment: "We need to use readlink because..." On POSIX systems, file won't say "Symbolic link" unless `-h` is specified. For GNU file, use `file -L [filename]`.

Comment: @Random832 Thanks! Yes, you're right, the manpage says `-L ... is the default if the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is defined.`

Answer (score 6):

A "pure" Vim way, just because we can:

```
:let is_64_bits = match(strpart(readfile(resolve('/proc/' . getpid() . '/exe'), 'b', 1)[0], 4, 1), '\%x02') != -1
```

So, how does it work? Split up in multiple commands:

1. Get the path to the Vim binary:

   ```
   :let file = resolve('/proc/' . getpid() . '/exe')
   ```
2. Read the first "line" of the current binary. Reading a "line" makes little
   sense for binary files, but AFAIK I can't tell Vim to read a *n* number of bytes:

   ```
   :let contents = readfile(file, 'b', 1)[0]
   ```
3. Get the fifth byte:

   ```
   :let magic = strpart(contents, 4, 1)
   ```
4. Check if this byte matches 0x02, if it does, it's a 64-bit binary. Using `== '\%x02'` or `=~ '\%x02'`  doesn't seem to work, so we use `match()`.

   ```
   :let is_64_bits = match(magic, '\%x02') != -1
   ```

   I got the "magic" byte value [from the `magic` file that the `file`
   command uses](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/file/file/master/magic/Magdir/elf):

   ```
   0   string      \177ELF     ELF
   !:strength *2
   >4  byte        0       invalid class
   >4  byte        1       32-bit
   >4  byte        2       64-bit
   ```

Note that just using `file` as per muru's answer is probably better; I'm not
sure if this works on all platforms/architectures (although a casual reading of the magic file suggests it would). I was mostly just curious to see if
this could be done from within VimScript without any external tools ;-)

Comment: If `readfile` supports reading from symlinks, then read directly from `/proc/$PID/exe`. I'm not sure how `resolve` will behave with deleted commands.

Comment: Once you reference `/proc` that way it isn't "pure Vim", it's "Linux Vim". :)

Comment: @lcd047 sort of but not really. `procfs` predates Linux by a decade, many systems have it. Linux did extend it heavily, and "as expected" in the world of Unix different implementations are not compatible ([`/proc/<pid>/path`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1473/proc-4.html#REFMAN4proc-4),
[`/proc/<pid>/file`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html))... Some systems may not have it, but making *anything* truly Unix-wide compatible without explicitly coding it (`#ifdef` etc.) is damn near impossible.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something! We're *within* Vim, so we don't need the PID. `/proc/self/exe`!